# What SQL Server version is my SSIS Package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jobs

Is there a list of `PackageFormatVersion` of SSIS packages and their SQL Server version compatible?

I have a `.dtsx` package to be run in SQL Server 2012 from a job in SQL Server 2008.

But it shows this error:

[image: job execution error]

So I migrated it from version 8 to 6. Does that work?

Is there a complete list of `.dtsx` package versions?

Answer (score 1):

- SQL Server 2005, runs SQL Server 2005 packages.
- SQL Server 2008/2008 R2 run SQL Server 2008/R2 packages and if presented with SQL Server 2005 packages updates them in memory to 2008 format, executes them and then discards the upgraded package information
- SQL Server 2012, runs 2012, 2008/R2, 2005 packages
- SQL Server 2014 RTM runs 2014, 2012, 2008/R2, 2005 Packages
- SQL Server 2016 introduced the ability to packages to be forwards and backwards compatible, where applicable. And the developers rejoiced as they only needed the current version of Visual Studio and SSIS tooling and they could just target older builds. And lo there was much rejoicing, and the people did feast upon the lambs, and sloths, and carp, and anchovies, and orangutans, and breakfast cereals, and fruit bats...

In your error message, you have SQL Server 2008 R2 (as noted by the 10.50.6560) dtexec.exe process running and it is trying to run a 2012 version of the package, which isn't an option.

You have two options as I see it. The first is to rewrite the 2012 package in 2008 because there's no downgrade option. It's too big of a leap. Back in the day, I'd tell people to reverse engineer the package into Biml and then emit the packages in Visual Studio 2008/2010 whatever it was and see if that worked. But I don't think Varigence supports 2008 targets any more and you'd need the SQL Server 2008 R2 installation media to get the Business Intelligence Design Studio (BIDS) installed on your machine to author the packages.

Hopefully, option 2 is actually an option for you. If the package is installed on a 2012 machine and further assuming it's in the SSISDB catalog, then you only have to solve the problem of running an stored procedure from 2008R2 on 2012. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-create-execution-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver16 That's probably a linked server but you could make it happen with a job. The 2008R2 box is going to be responsible for telling the package you need to run but you must ensure that the bits executing the SSIS package originate from 2012

Finally, while SQL Server 2008 R2 is out of support, they did release a security patch for it this year to roll that up to 10.50.6785.2 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/5021112

Comment: According to what you mentioned. Is going to be possible to run my dtsx package from a job living in sql server 2008? I am new at SSIS

Comment: A job living in SQL server 2008 will only be able to start a 2012 package if it can talk to the 2012 server. Maybe you define a job on 2012 that runs the v2012 package. Or the 2008 Agent job uses a Linked Server to call `server2012.SSISDB.catalog.create_execution ....` or lots of other ways but I don't yet know enough about what constraints are in place